# BizTalk BEC2004 Error while Validating Instance using a XML Document

Tags: xml, biztalk, xsd-validation, biztalk-2010

I am using BizTalk for the first time. I created a simple schema and simple XML document and trying to Validate the Instance. I am getting BEC2004 Error.

The Schema has The Employee Record with Name and ID attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
<xs:schema xmlns="http://myabc.xyz.Schema1" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com  /BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://myabc.xyz.Schema1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="Employee">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" /> 
             <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" /> 
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And I created a XML file with these fields alone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employee xmlns ="http://myabc.xyz.Schema1">
<Name>Dhana</Name>
<ID>001</ID>
</Employee >
```

The XML itself shows a error as The "http://myabc.xyz.Schema1" has not been declared.

If I validate the Instance I get error like

BEC2004 The element 'Employee' in namespace has invalid child element 'Name' in namespace 'http://myabc.xyz.Schema1'. List of possible elements expected: 'Name'.

Can anybody help me.

Comment: What version of BizTalk are you actually using?  You've tagged it with 3 different ones which is unlikely.

Comment: I am using BizTalk Server 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Form property of Name to Unqualified.  You will find that property on the Name element in the xsd file.